# Installing the latest build of packages

Tags: package-management

How can I install the latest build of a package? 
I am referring to the version of the package, because I see that other linux distros have more recent build of packages.

For example, ubuntu offers vlc 2.0.8 https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc/ meanwhile arch offers vlc 2.2.1 https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=vlc (a more recent package).

Comment: Install from source.

Comment: The latest build is in the repos. Not the same as latest upstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for its PPA or source. Ubuntu wants to make stuff easier for non-technical user, so it doesn't go behind latest which might have problems, but I agree sometimes Ubuntu is too late to the party and the cake is already eaten away.

If you want latest packages, then go for a distribution called Sabayon Linux [here](http://www.sabayonlinux.org) . They also have codecs, drivers pre-installed, chrome as well if that spy-machine interests you.

Also note, Sabayon is not debian based, but gentoo based, but they have a binary package manager, to make life easier.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

Every few days I run the following:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs
```

If there are any updates to what I have installed, I get them. I prefer to get my updates/upgrades from the official releases. I don't want any added problems with someones PPA's or repositories. If you must have the latest and greatest, be willing to accept the possibility of crashes and catastrophic failures. Best of luck!